# Java game engine for 2D RTS game in 2019

Tags: java, game-engine, 2d-games

I would like to ask you for an advice, what would be the best approach to create a RTS game in Java nowadays. I have some experience with JavaFX applications, but I guess it is not exactly inteded for such things and it is much better to use in "office" applications and there are not so many examples of games created using JavaFX. Or am I wrong and it can be used for that purpose?

I know there are such engines like Unity or Unreal, but I would like to make something like this in Java. Should I go for LWJGL or something like this in this case? I think that 2d engine should be enough for what I would like to do.

What would you recommend for that? Thanks for your suggestions. I know there are some topics like this, but I would like to know what is currently on top.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really a platform to ask for advice. I recommend you try Reddit/Quora instead.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'll go there in such case :) But I would like to say that I saw many topics asking for recommendation here on StackOverflow and getting a lot of attention and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL
You mentioned Unity and Unreal and this is certainly not comparabel with that. But in your headline you ask for a 2D engine and I think it fits in this category.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look on that! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's the java based (not specifically JavaFX) libgdx (https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which could be adapted to JavaFx.